# Client side querying of a web service across domains

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal

I've got a drupal web site on a `domain.com`. And I got a service at `sub.domain.com/service-name`.

The service accepts POST requests with form params and returns plain text.

On a page of the website, I've created a button with a jQuery $.post to call the service, but got an error because $.post cannot run across domains. I've installed the CORS plugin and allowed the calls to the subdomain but the error is the same.

Am I missing something?

If this is not the way to do it, what could be another way? Angular JS? Using static form and IFrame? I need to be pointed to the right direction.

Comment: Did you activate CORS on the server as well or only clientside with the JQuery plugin?

Comment: Only on the server using Drupal CORS plugin. What should I do on the client side?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS You'll have to add the withCredentials request header to your post request. Be aware that if you have to support IE9, there's a bug where the request has to be opened first before you set the withCredentials header. And make sure on the server that the allowed origins are fully written out. I had issues getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with value * to work in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Shilly but I really don't have time to read docs today, is there a line of javascript that I need to add to allow CORS at client side? What is the server side good for then?